# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.reflect.ConstantPool while running cucumber features

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber

[image: Using the 11.0.4 jdk in eclipse]I am using eclipse to run cucumber feature and I got this error.I have installed java 11.0.4.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by cucumber.runtime.java8.ConstantPoolTypeIntrospector (file:/Users/test1/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-java8/1.2.5/cucumber-java8-1.2.5.jar) to method java.lang.Class.getConstantPool()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of cucumber.runtime.java8.ConstantPoolTypeIntrospector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread “main” cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class test.sample.cucumber.steps.TestAPISteps
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:47)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:33)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.buildWorld(JavaBackend.java:131)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.buildBackendWorlds(Runtime.java:141)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:41)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/reflect/ConstantPool
    at cucumber.runtime.java8.ConstantPoolTypeIntrospector.getGenericTypes(ConstantPoolTypeIntrospector.java:29)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.Java8StepDefinition.getParameterInfos(Java8StepDefinition.java:54)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.Java8StepDefinition.<init>(Java8StepDefinition.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:162)
    at cucumber.api.java8.En.Given(En.java:199)
    at com.cbre.host.foodandbeverages.cucumber.steps.ProductStoreApiSteps.<init>(ProductStoreApiSteps.java:40)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.reflect.ConstantPool
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 19 more
```

What could be the reason of this ? 
This is happening only on my machine. On other machines, this issue is not replicated.
I have tried updating maven project. Tried and got the same issue on STS as well.

Both machine are having same java installed ..

```
java version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently using Cucumber JVM 1.2.5. This version of Cucumber can't run on Java 9 or higher. You may want to consider upgrading.

The latest released version of Cucumber JVM is 4.8.0. Note that the `groupId` has changed from `info.cukes` to `io.cucumber`.

Comment: That makes sense. But how is it that the same setup is working in other machines. I have java 11.0.4 installed, and using the same dependencies of cucumber (info.cukes). Strangely its working perfectly fine there.

Comment: The logical conclusion would be that you do not have the same setup despite evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

Your other machines must be running on java8. Your error trace is suggesting to use java8.

```
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of cucumber.runtime.java8.ConstantPoolTypeIntrospector
```

Comment: I checked I have java 11.0.4 installed on the other machine.outside and in eclipse also.

Comment: Both the machines have same java installed 11.0.4

Comment: java version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS, mixed mode)

Comment: Try to run this code on java8. is it working on jdk8?

Comment: No .. not working on java8 .. giving the same error

Comment: I checked again in eclipse and found that i was actually using java8 as jre in eclipse run time..